# python scrape data usa gov

Tags: python, sockets, web

I get following error

'IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known'

when I try to scrape data from:

http://1usagov.measuredvoice.com/2013/

any idea what may be the reason?

here is my code:

```
import urllib
import re

import time

data = urllib.urlopen('http://1usagov.measuredvoice.com/2013/').read()
# print data
print data
# datafiles name pattern - usagov_bitly_data2011-07-29-1311919454
p = re.compile('usagov_bitly_data\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{10}')
# print p.findall('<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="usagov_bitly_data2011-07-29-1311919454">usagov_bitly_data2011-07-29-1311919454</a></td><td align="right">29-Jul-2011 07:04  </td><td')

m = p.findall(data)

# print m

for i in range(len(m)):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        print m[i]

# time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.localtime(epoch))

print len(m)

for i in range(len(m)):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        print "downloading ", m[i]
        clicks = urllib.urlopen('http://bitly.measuredvoice.com/bitly_archive/' + m[i]).read()
        file = open(m[i], "w")
        file.write(clicks)
        file.close()
        print "done"
```

edit:

full traceback added

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = urllib.urlopen('http://1usagov.measuredvoice.com/2013/').read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 778, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: As a general rule, please provide full traceback, not just error message.

Comment: ... just added it

Comment: but you see I am stopped in line 6 so I can not print m[i]

Comment: ...Standard output is empty

Comment: The URL does not seem to work. Please double check. Using ping, I get `ping: unknown host http://1usagov.measuredvoice.com/`, which explains the urllib error.

Comment: if you open the url it works ... the problem is it redirects you ... and once redirected there is loads of file i want to scrap

Comment: I can't reach this URL from my machine and network-tools.com either.

Comment: hmm...I can not ping it as well but I can open it ...

Comment: DNS issue? What if you clean your DNS cache?